# Website Reviews - Dynamically Displaying an image of the front of other websites

Tags: php, html, image

I've been building a website page that reviews other pages and with the review it would be great to also show an image of the front of the site as it currently looks.

eg: Review 1
Website Name & Domain name
Review Text
Image of front of page.

I know I can get the images of the fronts of pages manually and add them in as STD HTML  etc tags.

But I wanted to ask if there was a way to do this dynamically so it would always be current.

Is this possible?
Are there any issues with doing this?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried squeezeFrame?

Shrinking contents is sometimes not the easiest thing to do but the plugin comes pretty darn close to the best thing for your situation.

http://futtta.be/squeezeFrame/